# How do I tell why a php script has failed?

Tags: php, wordpress, scheduled-tasks

I am running a Wordpress site in which I am migrating posts from non-WP site to a Wordpress site.  The site I am migrating has about 5000 posts so I created a tool that I kickoff from the admin area using `wp_schedule_single_event()`.  The event fires and starts OK and isn't having problems getting posts or inserting them.

However, after about 12 minutes or so, the process fails and doesn't report any fatal errors.  Can someone tell me how I can debug the process since it is running under wp-cron?  I have added the following to my script and it doesn't report and warnings or errors:

```
set_time_limit(0); // no time limit
error_reporting(-1); // log everything
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1); // no memory limit
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

I know some others have asked similar questions but their resolutions haven't helped me.

Comment: And what is the process?  What is the tool?  There is nothing in the code above that we can use to help you.

Comment: The process is a php script that is registered with Wordpress via the wp_schedule_single_event call.  I added the code above so that you wouldn't point out the obvious like timeouts and memory usage since I have already addressed those.  The question is still valid without posting all of my code -- something is terminating a long running WP scheduled job; how would one go about debugging that?

Comment: Have you considered there may be something wrong with your process?  Please post the code.

Answer (score 1):

It could be quite a number of issues, timeout, database exception to name a few. You can use try/catch blocks. The try block will hold your code and the catch block will be used to handle an exception in the event one is thrown.

An example below:

```
try {
    // your code goes here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // log/print error
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

The Exception class specified as the catch param is the base class so it will catch EVERY exception, which is probably what you want in your situation.

More about exceptions: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Thanks Rijndael -- I am using try/catch blocks but no exceptions are being caught.  Out of curiosity, wouldn't anything that you have listed above trigger something in the php log?

Comment: Fatal Errors are logged, exceptions aren't always logged. If you do want to log them then user error_log(). Since you are using WP, it may very well be that WP has some global flag set which is preventing logs from being generated. A quick search has revealed define('WP_DEBUG', true); and define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true); - I found them here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php - I am not aware of the scope of these flags but for production it is a VERY bad idea to show error messages to users, so be careful. See this URI for more:

Comment: I added that but there isn't anything that popped up in the log.  Since it's a scheduled task, these actually don't do too much as they just show errors when you're on a page.  Appreciate you looking into it, though.  Perhaps I'll just create a new thread and post my code.

Comment: if you are running a schedule then use error_log($e->getMessage(), 0); in the catch part of the try/catch block. That will log any exceptions into the default logs, which usually is the apache logs.